# Prohibir y obligar (a hacer) - ¿provocan la aparición del modo subjuntivo?

Tags: verbos, subjuntivo, sintaxis

Me gustaría saber si hay casos en los que los verbos *prohibir* y *obligar (a hacer)* provocan el uso de subjuntivo. Todos los ejemplos que encontré van con infinitivo ya que el sujeto del infinitivo y el sujeto del verbo principal es el mismo.

¿Es la combinación *"prohibir/obligar + que + subjuntivo"* posible?

¡Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sí - cada tipo de petición/orden (en la forma `verbo + que`) obliga que se *use* el subjuntivo, ej:

> *...Francia prohíbe que los menores de 15 años **usen** celulares en la...*
>
> - [Google News: "prohíbe que"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22proh%C3%ADbe+que%22&source=lnms&tbm=nws)

> *...se obliga que **haya** infraestructura para ciclovías...*
>
> - [Google News: "obliga que"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22obliga+que%22&source=lnms&tbm=nws)

Aquí hay los grupos semánticos de palabras/frases que provocan el subjuntivo (salvo que los rojos):

[image]

Comment: ahhh, si, cualquier construcción de ese tipo te obliga te lleva al subjuntivo

Comment: @ukemi, no se si sean regionalismos, errores u otro tipo de frases que se expresan, pero entre las posibilidades o hipótesis, se pueden hacer frases de indicativo con las 5 últimas opciones que no están resaltadas. Por ej.  (Puede ser que / Posiblemente / Quizás / Tal vez) intento dar una respuesta válida.